# order and invoice email no longer sending automatically 2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1, email, invoice, order-email, send-mail

The order and invoice emails have all of a sudden stopped sending automatically,  they can still be sent manually by clicking on 'send email'  there seems to be no issue on the email server, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you made any modification lately? Usually this happens when the cronjob isn't doing it's job. Verify that your cron tab is running with a valid configuration.